# I need to send encrypted post data in x-www-form-urlencoded format using python

Tags: python, api, encryption, python-requests, cryptography

i have to send encrypted data in

```
x-www-form-urlencoded
```

using python

I tried encrypting the data using cryptography module using fernet
the data i have to send is in dictionary form

```
message = {'Id':1,'Desktop':dtop[0],'Mobile':mob[0]}
message1=json.dumps(message)
print(message1)

key = Fernet.generate_key()
print('key',key)
fernet = Fernet(key)

encrypted = fernet.encrypt(message1.encode())
print('Encrypted Success')
```

what should i do next to send this as post req

Answer (score 0):

Thats how you can send `x-www-form-urlencoded` data in a request

```
url = "http://example.com/"
headers = {"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
data = {"data": encrypted}
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
print(response.text)
```